# проверка есть ли элемент в базе данных sqlite андроид

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Делаю приложение - магазин. Избранное и корзина реализованы через базу данных sqlite. При добавлении товара в избранное нужно проверить нет ли этого товара в таблице и только тогда добавлять.

Comment: Так проверьте в таблице, а проблема-то в чем?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja я не знаю как это реализовать. Находила примеры кода, но не получается.

Comment: Что именно не знаете? Как SQL-запросы писать или у вас Room или еще чего? https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#ReadDbRow

Comment: Запрос на поиск я могу написать, но я не понимаю как вернуть условное true, если есть товар для одного действия и false чтоб я вызвала метод записи в базу данных. @EugeneKrivenja

Comment: А представьте как человек со стороны, который вообще вашего проекта не видел, должен это понять. Пишите код и задавайте конкретный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создай метод в нем объяви курсор и в условии проверь, есть ли там в этом курсоре элемент. Что-то типо такого будет

```
public bool GetItem(string itemName){
        bool check;
        try{
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor checkCursor = db.rawQuery(String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE item=%s","название таблицы",itemName),null);    
            if(checkCursor.moveToFirst()){
                check=true;
            }
            else{
                check=false;
            }
            checkCursor.close();
            db.close();
            return check;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("DBHelper.GetCheck",e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Естественно что SQL-запрос надо подправить под твой